# Запятая при повторяющихся союзах

Tags: пунктуация

**И я щеку вторую подставлю**

**И тому(,) и тому подлецу.**

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"?

UPD:
 1. Подлец - обобщающее слово? 2. Можно ли трактовать "и тому и тому" как фразеологизм или цельное сочетание?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Всё зависит от контекста:** о чём речь, сколько действующих лиц? Если всем подлецам, то запятая ставится. Если же их только двое, то здесь обнаруживается **тесное единство** (обоим), тогда запятая не нужна.

(1) И я щеку вторую подставлю **И тому, и тому подлецу (всем).**
(1) И я щеку вторую подставлю **И тому и тому подлецу (обоим)**.

Что касается фразеологических сочетаний, то их эта тема касается в первую очередь, но их наличие не является обязательным ―  достаточно тесного единства. Кстати, понимание "тесного единства" может быть **авторским**.

По Розенталю: [§ 13. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)

При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется **тесное смысловое единство**: Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму старую жокейскую кепку (Пауст.); Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону (Сем.); Он был и весел и печален в одно и то же время.

Примеры:

Марья Ивановна, передавая все это мне в Москве, верила **и тому и другому** варианту, то есть **всему вместе.** [Ф. М. Достоевский. Подросток (1875)]

Так что Сосновый стал иногда сниться **им** по ночам. **И тому, и другому.** (Сергей Залыгин)

А ведь **и тому, и другому** равно нужно было, чтобы взмолился Аввакум: «Помилуйте». [Ю. М. Нагибин. Огненный протопоп (1972-1979)]

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна - нет ни обобщающего слова, ни зависимых слов.

> ...**При двукратном повторении** других **союзов, кроме и**, запятая
>   ставится всегда.

Теперь об особенностях постановки запятой при двукратном повторении союза ***и***.

> При двукратном повторении союза *и* (если число однородных членов —
>   два) **запятая ставится при наличии обобщающего слова** при однородных
>   членах предложения: *Всё напоминало об осени: и желтые листья, и
>   туманы по утрам;* то же без обобщающего слова, но **при наличии
>   зависимых слов** при однородных членах: *Теперь уж можно было
>   расслышать в отдельности и шум дождя, и шум воды* (Булг.).
>
> Однако **при отсутствии указанных условий при однородных членах
>   предложения, образующих тесное смысловое единство, запятая может не
>   ставиться**: *Кругом было и светло и зелено* (Т.); *И днем и ночью кот
>   ученый все ходит по цепи кругом* (П.).

Примечание-1:

> Не следует путать повторяющийся союз *и* и союзы *и*, поставленные на
>   разном основании: *Было тихо и темно, и сладко пахло травами* (первое
>   *и* стоит между однородными частями главного члена предложения, а второе *и* присоединяет часть сложного предложения).

Примечание-2:

> **Не ставится запятая в цельных фразеологизированных сочетаниях с повторяющимися союзами *и... и***, ни... ни (они соединяют слова с
>   противопоставляемыми значениями): *и день и ночь, и стар и млад, и
>   смех и горе, и там и сям, и то и се, и туда и сюда, ни два ни полтора,
>   ни дать ни взять, ни сват ни брат, ни взад ни вперед, ни дна ни
>   покрышки, ни то ни се, ни стать ни сесть, ни жив ни мертв, ни да ни
>   нет, ни слуху ни духу, ни себе ни людям, ни рыба ни мясо, ни так ни
>   сяк, ни пава ни ворона, ни шатко ни валко, ни тот ни этот* и др. То же
>   при парных сочетаниях слов, когда третьего не дано: *и муж и жена, и
>   земля и небо.*

**[источник](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=74)**

---

После внесения дополнений в вопрос.

Обобщающее выглядело бы так:

*И я щеку вторую подставлю обоим подлецам: и тому, и тому.*

С одним зависимым словом у нас не получится ни фразеологизма, ни цельного сочетания.

---

[Розенталь:](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm)

> При двух однородных членах с повторяющимся союзом и запятая не
>   ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие
>   однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов), например:
>   *Были и лето и осень дождливы...* (Жуковский); *Кругом было и светло и зелено* (Тургенев); *Ой, полна, полна коробушка, есть и ситец и парча*
>   (Некрасов); *Он ею и жил и дышал* (А.К. Толстой); *Прибрежная полоса,
>   пересеченная мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону* (Семушкин).
>
> **При наличии у однородных членов пояснительных слов запятая в этих случаях** обычно **ставится**, например: *...В вашем сердце есть и
>   гордость, и прямая честь* (Пушкин); *Срубленные осины придавили собой
>   и траву, и мелкий кустарник* (Тургенев); *Все вокруг переменилось: и
>   природа, и характер леса* (Л. Толстой).

"Наш" случай - *и та и другая сторона*.

Comment: Разве "подлецу" - не обобщающее слово? А если нет, то не зависимое слово?

Comment: Да,как заметили выше :  1.Подлец - обобщающее слово? 2.Можно ли трактовать "и тому и тому" как фразеологизм или цельное сочетание? Скорее всего, я некорректно задал вопрос.Обновлю.

Comment: Не обобщающее - точно, а зависимое - да, но оно только одно, а нужна парочка!